# Geometric meaning of the dot Product in Multivaraible calculus

Tags: geometry, vectors, inner-products

I am going through MIT's course on Multivariable calculus Given by Herbert Gross. In the Dot product section of the question is as follows : With A and B as in part (a) use the result of part (b) to interpret geometrically the set of all vectors C for which A • B = A • C, where we proved in part B that A is perpendicular to (B-C).

Answer in the book is : Since we have already agreed that vectors do not depend on their
point of origin, let us assume, without loss of generality, that
and B originate at a common point, the origin.
Now, the locus of all vectors V such that A • V = 0 is the ***plane*** to
which  A is perpendicular. (Again, for the sake of uniformity, we -f
are assuming that all vectors V start at the origin.) A picture is provided.

Q1: Why can I bring any vector back to the Origin (0,0,0) ?
Q2: How is it that the set of all vectors perpendicular to A (called V) is a Plane. I thought to get a plane you need two independent vector to span a plan, there is no mention of that here.

I was thinking simply that all this means is that if i have any vectors B and C then their difference B-C is always perpendicular to A.

Q3: What is the purpose of all this construction of plane and point OP and what not ?
[image: Pictorially]

Comment: One issue with the solution is, the plane drawn is not the plane being discussed. (!) The plane being discussed is _orthogonal to_ $A$, but _passes through_ (the tip of) $B$, and does not contain $O$ unless $A \cdot B = A \cdot O = 0$. <> Does that help?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang hey, i am sorry i don't quite get what you mean to be honest. Is there any way you can direct me to a picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: In Euclidean geometry, translation unambiguously identifies vectors based at different points. In fancy terms, *parallel transport is path-independent*.

A2: We do need two vectors to *span* a plane, but (in three-dimensional Euclidean geometry) a non-zero vector $\vec{A}$ is *normal* to a plane, really, to a unique one-parameter family of pairwise disjoint, mutually-parallel planes.

A3: The purposes of this construction are too numerous to summarize. As explanation for the comment:

[image: A plane in three-space defined by constant dot product with a fixed vector]

Comment: Hey Andrew, i really appreciate the image and the answer. I still don't get it unfortunately, i think its above my current level of understanding right now but thank you again for the answer.

Comment: Not sure if the acceptance came after your comment and you're now happy. If not, it may help to assume $A$ is a unit vector, so the dot product $A \cdot B$ is the component of $B$ along $A$. The set of vectors having the same component in this sense is a plane, specifically the plane perpendicular to the line spanned by $A$ and passing through the scalar multiple of $A$ having the same component as $B$, namely $(A \cdot B)A$. <> If you get another answer that better suits you, please do accept it instead.